# Biblatex, citing with endnotes, ibid tracker gets thrown off

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, endnotes, enotez

Consider the output below, created with `biblatex`  and its vanilla authoryear-icomp scheme, with the citations placed in endnotes (using the `enotez` package).

[image]

There isn't much that seems wrong about it. That is, until you know that the third citation command in fact points to Malinowski rather than to Knuth.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext,enotez}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,notetype=endonly,autocite=footnote,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib}

\let\footnote\endnote%

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\footcite{malinowski}

\blindtext
\footnote{That's also what \textcite{knuth:ct} says.}

\blindtext
\footcite{malinowski}

\printendnotes
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Notes 1 and 3 are produced using the regular `\footcite` command, which is sufficient since no comments are added to the citation. Note 2 though is a `\footnote` with a citation embedded in some text.

Nothing too special, but it seems that that's enough to confuse biblatex's ibid tracker. It doesn't seem to take note of what's happening inside note 2.

It may well be that there's something I've overlooked (in that case, what is it?). But if you people think it's something that I should contact the biblatex team about, I'll of course do that.

PS: just to clarify: this does not happen when foot- rather than endnotes are used. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc1f2.png

Comment: AFAICS `biblatex` currently doesn't patch `enotez`' `\endnote` command so that `biblatex` doesn't know it is in a footnote if you use `\footnote`/`\endnote` (if you use `\footcite` biblatex does that automatically). By default `biblatex` has two tracking levels and it gets tangled up in those. I couldn't figure out how to patch `enotez` properly, so a work-around is `ibidtracker=true` if you don't have citations in the text.

Answer (score 3):

Currently `biblatex` doesn't support the `enotez` package in that it can't patch `enotez`' commands for footnote (endnote) detection.

You could just ignore the distinction between footnote and text via `ibidtracker=true`, but that might not be the best option for you.

I managed to modify some `enotez` internals to include the footnote detection toggle, and it worked in the MWE

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_undefine:N \enotez_endnote:nn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \enotez_endnote:nn #1#2
  {
    \enotez_endnote_mark:n  {#1}
    \enotez_endnote_text:nn {#1} {\toggletrue{blx@footnote}#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

That is a bit of a kludge, though.

Comment: This seems to work: `\ExplSyntaxOn \pretocmd \enotez_get_note:nn { \toggletrue {blx@footnote} } {} {patch~failed} \ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: What's more bothering to me is that the log keeps telling `Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file`

Comment: Thanks @clemens, will give that a try. @moewe: luckily, `ibidtracker=true` *is* a good option in my case, as I've stopped using in-text citations in all documents where I'm control over what citation scheme gets used. So there's only one level on which citations appear.

Comment: @clemens If that is the preferred way to get the toggle in, you could ask the `biblatex` team to implement `enotez` support with that patch. The rerun message problem is a general  one with `enotez` though, even `\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,autocite=footnote,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\let\footnote\endnote%

\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{malinowski}

\printendnotes
\printbibliography
\end{document}` prompted me to rerun all the time. (I guess it has to do with how citations are handled in aux files?)

Comment: I could add the patch to `enotez` without having to bother the biblatex team... I'll try to figure out the rerun problem and fix it, too.

Comment: @clemens Or you can do that. I don't know about the official line about who should be doing that implementation (if you let them know they can at least add `enotez` to the list of supported packages.)

Comment: @clemens BTW: If you are trying to tackle the `.aux` file problem, be warned that some of the `.aux` file handling is going to change in `biblatex` 3.4 (currently on github dev branch).

Comment: @clemens I think I figured out the rerun problem: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/707. Would it be possible to include the `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}` in `enotez`? `biblatex` only patches a few packages (apparently the policy was to only patch the 'big' ones) and doesn't do LaTeX3 at the moment.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the reminder. I'll update `enotez` (https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/enotez/issues/11/)