# Reset Chapter Endnotes

Tags: footnotes, biblatex-chicago, endnotes

I'm working on a very large report with a variety of endnotes (using both \footnote and \autocite commands). I need to have the endnotes reset with each chapter (ie. restart at 1). Minimal working example as follows,

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

 \renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter*{\notesname}\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
    \makeatletter
        \@addtoreset{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering every new chapter
    \makeatother
\usepackage{footmisc}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Alpha}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text with footnote.\footnote{ \autocite{B02}}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\theendnotes

\chapter{Bravo}

Some text \autocite{B02}.

Some text \autocite{C03}.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

I'm curious if the preamble I included is the most efficient (or minimal) solution to my desired outcome? This block of code seems a bit unwieldy and trying to refine my LaTeX coding. In other words, is there a simpler or shorter preamble that I can include yet still achieve my desired outcome of resetting the endnote number every chapter?

```
 \renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter*{\notesname}\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
    \makeatletter
        \@addtoreset{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering every new chapter
    \makeatother
\usepackage{footmisc}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks OK, but can be shortened a bit.

On first glance, the `\renewcommand\enoteheading` looks a bit odd with all the `\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip`, but that is also what the original definition in `endnotes.sty` does (and it is required for correct alignment of the endnotes).

But if the endnotes are per-chapter endnotes, I would not set the endnotes themselves as chapters. Logically I'd have thought the endnotes belong to the previous chapter and should therefore be a section of that chapter...

With a current version of LaTeX (at least April 2018), you can use `\counterwithin*` instead of `\@addtoreset`. This has two advantages

1. You don't need `\makeatletter...\makeatother` because `\counterwithin*` does not contain an `@`.
2. `\counterwithin*` checks that its arguments are counters. (Not really necessary here, since you know what you are passing should be counters).

It is not clear to me that you need

```
\usepackage{footmisc}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
```

I don't think I could see a difference in the example when I omitted it. (Since you have redirected all footnotes to endnotes, which use their own counter, at least the `\thefootnote` redefinition seems useless.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter*{\notesname}\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Alpha}
Some text \autocite{sigfridsson}.

Some text with footnote.\footnote{\autocite{worman}}

Some text \autocite{sigfridsson}.

\theendnotes

\chapter{Bravo}
Some text \autocite{worman}.

Some text \autocite{geer}.

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[How does one get endnotes at the end of every chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9475/35864) also mentions a way to produce per-chapter endnotes with the `pagenote` package.

I would has suggested looking at `enotez`, but currently `biblatex` does not patch `enotez`, so the footnote detection does not quite work (cf. [Biblatex, citing with endnotes, ibid tracker gets thrown off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304457/35864)).

Comment: moewe, Is this still a pending issue? What is really required from the point of view of `biblatex` so that citations work in an end note context? Is it sufficient to set `\toggletrue { blx@footnote }`? I ask because I'm working on some related stuff and for me it would be critical to get `biblatex` running smoothly with it. (I understand that part of the problem for `enotez` is an expansion which occurs when the .aux file is read. I don't have this particular issue. So what I'd love to know is, excluded .aux file issues, is setting the boolean sufficient?)

Comment: @gusbrs What do you mean by this? The MWE here works fine as far as I can see. One big concern when you implement footnotes (or related things) differently is indeed that `biblatex` needs to know we're in a footnote-like environment (we need the `blx@footnote` toggle). I can imagine that there are more issues, but I guess those will mostly depend on the exact implementation of your footnotes (e.g. expansion issues when the footnotes are written to a file, cite context [refsection etc.]).

Comment: Sorry, moewe, I didn't mean the answer, but your comment about the relation between `enotez` and `biblatex`, saying that "footnote detection does not quite work". So `blx@footnote` is required for `biblatex` to know it is in a footnote-like environment, I got that covered. I suppose the requirement is handling idem and ibidem trackers. So far I haven't stumbled in expansion issues, since I don't write the notes contents to a file at all. About the relation between refsection and cite context, I have to think, it may be tricky indeed. I may pester you again later on... And thank you!

Comment: Rereading my comment, I see why you didn't understand what it was about. There was no way to, sorry.  :-)